# longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length [error]

Tags: r

So I am currently getting an error

```
Error in data.frame(PTS, P3M, REB = OREB + DREB, AST, TOV, STL, BLK, PF) : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 605, 30
In addition: Warning message:
In OREB + DREB :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

My code is as follows in R, version 3.5.3

```
library('BasketballAnalyzeR')
RNGkind(sample.kind = "Rounding")
attach(Pbox)
View(Pbox)
data <- data.frame(PTS, P3M, REB=OREB+DREB, AST, TOV, STL, BLK, PF)
NROW(OREB)
detach(Pbox)
```

I'm confused how NROW(OREB) gives me a row count of 361 and NROW(DREB) gives me a row count of 605. I saved the data as a .csv file and OREB and DREB columns perfectly have 605 values in their respective columns. I've seen similar questions regarding the same error but didn't find a solution. I've tried reinstalling the packet, restart my computer (lol), restart R, since it logically does not make sense to me

Comment: Your code works fine on my machine. No error. No differing number of rows.

Comment: @stefan figured that would be the case. I'm just so perplexed by the error - really don't know what's going wrong. I've put the code on a different script, restarted my computer like I mentioned lol, and reinstalled the package. I'll try to troubleshoot it myself for now I guess, but thanks for lmk it works for you

Comment: The code works fine also on my machine.

Answer (score 1):

You should almost never use `attach()`, because it leads to confusion like this.  What `attach(Pbox)` does is to put `Pbox` second on the search list, after the global environment.  You can see the variables in the global environment by running

```
ls()
```

I'd guess one of the `Pbox` column names is also a variable in the global environment, and is being found first.  You probably ignored a warning like `The following object is masked _by_ .GlobalEnv: OREB`.

A better approach if you want to save typing is

```
data <- with(Pbox, data.frame(PTS, P3M, REB=OREB+DREB, AST, TOV, STL, BLK, PF))
```

This puts `Pbox` ahead of the global environment for the duration of that line, so you'll find the variables you expect to be finding.